# Find log-likelihood using the predicted probabilities in r

Tags: r, log-likelihood

I built a `glm` model and used it to predict probabilities for the test data.

```
model = glm(y ~ x, data=dt, family=binomial(link='logit'))
pred = predict(model, newdata=test.dt, type='response')
```

How do I find the test log-likelihood for the predicted probabilities?

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible piece of your data on which you want to apply the model and extract the log-likelihood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```r
dbinom(dt$y, prob=pred, size=1, log=TRUE)
```

should give you the log-likelihood (assuming that these are binary/Bernoulli responses). You could also calculate the log-likelihood directly as `dt$y*log(pred) + (1-dt$y)*log(1-pred)` (I think)

If you want the combined log-likelihood just `sum()` the above value ... or `logLik(model)`